# Wifi problems with Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, 20.04

So I did a clean installation from 18.04 LTS to this new version, and I am really liking it, but I usually connect an Ethernet cable for the installation, the thing is that when I disconnected I found out that I have the same problem that I had with Pop OS some years ago, I have a laptop with the Realtek RTL8822BE WiFi card, and Bluetooth works great, but when I enable WiFi no networks show up.

I already tried `sudo service network-manager` and didn't work, I have noticed that it has downloaded some sort of driver for it, as it doesn't appear in Additional Drivers

maybe this helps:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 23 Apr 2020 20:38 -05 -0500

Booted last: 23 Apr 2020 00:00 -05 -0500

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3526 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5a03 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211              843776  2 rtwpci,rtw88
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
cfg80211              704512  2 mac80211,rtw88
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
asus_wmi               32768  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    32768  2 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  49152  2 asus_wmi,i915

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.9/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 84179sec preferred_lft 84179sec
    inet6 fe80::24cf:3fcc:c7bd:43e3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.9 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        4032       1  0 20:00 ?        00:00:10 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       22738187-3f7d-3038-8e90-6bef4a130dc7
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.9/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             200.21.200.10
IP4.DNS[2]:                             200.21.200.80
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 200.21.200.10 200.21.200.80
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1587776461
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.9
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::24cf:3fcc:c7bd:43e3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   22738187-3f7d-3038-8e90-6bef4a130dc7 | Wired connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtw_pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.4.0-26-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Bogota (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     903F9DC753D67350BFBEC9F
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-26-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        2E:1C:6B:CE:DF:4D:6E:F0:5B:25:79:E8:B6:0E:F2:9A:9A:01:CB:AF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      2B:5C:FC:D8:EF:9D:04:F8:88:28:B5:A8:60:84:B4:59:A5:EE:F1:0B:
        D2:92:A2:2D:62:67:99:35:2C:99:1A:8A:B5:CE:9E:C9:09:49:26:1D:
        B0:12:5C:28:EE:89:BF:BC:CB:65:A1:1C:17:25:C8:31:04:77:27:6D:
        A6:68:C9:F0:13:77:8A:7E:4F:7A:68:A5:17:EE:A2:9C:0D:96:0A:3D:
        47:09:0A:E0:26:FF:5E:98:C6:B5:39:B6:DB:B7:69:26:56:4D:A8:20:
        42:A9:79:9D:06:98:8F:29:D5:24:84:91:3D:BF:D9:DF:01:D7:DD:D5:
        ED:5B:E1:F6:FC:A1:46:E3:89:CC:3C:B0:80:D2:8D:F2:DE:E5:1B:C0:
        EA:AA:3B:B2:75:A8:1A:0B:E3:88:F4:36:4A:DD:C6:4F:FB:73:A9:E4:
        12:C1:FE:30:42:C1:53:A1:2D:22:80:7A:20:4F:D9:B2:3B:FD:C8:61:
        35:B8:4A:41:CB:D4:BC:86:94:F3:D3:C1:D5:A4:DE:9E:C8:D7:92:6A:
        D4:56:F9:8A:35:6C:22:25:88:43:4D:47:13:63:26:AE:5C:D1:64:EA:
        39:55:D7:D9:F1:08:C2:A4:76:39:5D:6B:91:41:6A:10:41:34:8C:C3:
        06:A6:EE:81:61:F8:00:CA:97:A8:39:8D:00:E9:A2:7C:29:A2:BF:C9:
        0C:2C:2C:9D:66:43:6D:53:B3:ED:EA:16:C3:8E:EF:22:0D:FE:20:5E:
        CD:B7:9B:BC:9A:B0:F3:4A:D8:D2:A9:22:A8:9A:D4:F6:80:EF:9F:FC:
        73:3B:EC:A7:7D:E5:1B:0D:DC:FB:E8:08:31:97:E7:7D:FE:87:7C:3A:
        04:31:F6:67:E0:9E:BB:E0:48:75:D2:AB:53:2B:92:A7:84:67:A0:11:
        06:0A:7A:1C:04:E7:B0:BF:B2:CD:B9:41:65:71:6A:46:2F:B4:D5:CD:
        49:0D:C5:96:30:AC:A1:D0:2D:6F:AA:1C:9B:D8:5F:C2:2C:30:7C:43:
        CE:E0:E6:3B:40:E2:73:EF:C0:B3:92:61:8E:2D:A2:32:28:B9:41:56:
        B7:BE:58:43:81:10:31:CE:43:99:F6:51:26:64:0D:CC:75:95:F4:68:
        02:B4:A2:A2:A9:C9:D7:64:8A:CE:92:80:D8:05:8B:CD:D1:94:97:56:
        54:3F:9C:24:8F:A5:82:43:A7:C9:DA:0D:99:4F:66:43:6D:D2:72:F3:
        2A:6B:5C:5A:3E:7E:25:BC:53:9B:D9:A2:CE:B3:ED:E0:80:8F:82:D3:
        ED:0C:E9:95:6B:D1:B9:BC:1C:9B:4A:2F:A0:18:66:AD:69:9C:AF:A1:
        C1:90:0C:96:AC:C7:1E:17:C5:CC:70:1A
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     8795FC14A499B3F7A2F6AD8
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-26-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        2E:1C:6B:CE:DF:4D:6E:F0:5B:25:79:E8:B6:0E:F2:9A:9A:01:CB:AF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      2B:BE:F5:0E:F8:79:0A:5A:28:AA:E7:CD:D2:DA:FE:D8:D3:EF:7F:A2:
        2F:0D:AD:65:F1:AD:D9:74:29:73:54:B8:C7:7D:9E:6C:EC:46:6F:1D:
        7F:12:C6:DF:95:3C:52:3A:1A:47:12:40:B8:66:48:F3:FF:49:28:44:
        2A:ED:96:AD:07:48:7A:F7:19:D4:10:F9:A5:4E:90:A8:FD:8A:02:14:
        AA:31:06:91:5E:2C:58:DA:3D:8F:20:2F:D3:21:99:2C:B7:CF:4E:53:
        33:3E:F5:45:7D:8C:23:71:24:8B:7D:61:87:55:60:B7:72:FA:0C:08:
        D1:B0:0B:BF:D3:DC:56:22:F9:94:7D:C6:F8:8B:35:27:8B:A3:14:B7:
        90:15:B8:93:C7:A8:3F:B5:69:24:4B:D7:27:50:4B:A5:D5:D1:45:85:
        AB:0C:4E:84:9D:33:B1:BC:E0:31:C5:92:73:90:46:17:AB:0C:4C:31:
        49:C2:0D:AC:52:88:9F:5D:7A:2B:EF:75:1D:D1:9D:92:D2:FD:88:0D:
        74:D8:C7:41:0D:54:67:D6:66:E9:C5:C8:3F:94:E0:86:2B:D5:38:D7:
        07:95:B8:3B:A5:96:F9:20:D6:2C:BC:DA:22:C4:97:DD:FB:1C:8B:ED:
        15:EC:33:95:65:FE:36:7B:93:44:6B:1D:57:91:C4:C4:31:EE:2D:17:
        2D:FD:E8:2F:50:C3:48:3A:0A:0D:F1:1B:53:D1:A3:9E:5B:A8:1C:56:
        99:79:BE:1B:E0:F1:5B:BD:28:96:2B:A6:F8:DD:34:05:84:9E:04:D3:
        26:58:24:64:9C:0D:CC:46:A2:3E:27:1D:35:F3:81:E1:98:78:89:07:
        D1:09:63:80:D0:79:48:21:95:84:62:17:32:3B:C9:67:98:22:D2:26:
        3E:B5:3A:25:EF:BE:42:CE:99:A1:50:D0:4D:70:28:94:31:9D:63:DA:
        78:5A:BD:8A:8B:78:76:DA:40:33:3E:D8:9D:D5:C7:CF:6B:5F:05:47:
        E2:30:AE:2A:C8:42:36:14:21:5E:93:B9:70:3B:16:00:49:F9:28:A6:
        23:76:A2:03:1A:A1:CE:42:08:55:E7:FD:39:62:50:E9:E1:73:58:60:
        75:B9:44:7E:4F:17:CF:1A:19:20:56:A4:43:38:FC:9F:2C:7E:C0:C2:
        FE:C2:AF:73:C7:8F:76:8E:CB:72:D9:FD:1C:9D:06:1B:30:99:3B:5C:
        6F:2B:DC:CB:71:3F:FC:C3:4F:DF:CE:B4:77:F2:A9:9E:8D:5D:90:A9:
        52:02:1A:EE:B3:D1:ED:6E:19:81:FC:3A:2E:48:BA:26:E8:F8:52:D7:
        62:5C:AE:7C:88:2B:29:87:0C:60:A3:23
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf]
options r8822be aspm=0

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  938.935118] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  938.935145] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

I have no clue what to do, I have tried everything that I have seen on forums and nothing has fixed it, I hope someone can help me.

Anyway I think that maybe this is a problem of the release as it's brand new and just came out today, and probably not many people have this awful card.

Thanks,

Comment: I feel your pain, I'm dealing with a ton of wifi problems here too. 5 computers in my house (including phones) and only the linux machine is having wifi issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution I found on another forum.  Looks like it has worked for some others quite well.  I have not tried it myself since I don't have the same issue.

Change directory:

`cd /lib/firmware`

Make Directory rtw88

`sudo mkdir rtw88`

Copy rtl8822befw.bin to the directory you just created:

`sudo cp /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8822befw.bin /lib/firmware/rtw88/`

Rename that file to rtw8822b_fw.bin:

`sudo mv /lib/firmware/rtw88/rtl8822befw.bin /lib/firmware/rtw88/rtw8822b_fw.bin`

reboot your system

Comment: Well, it didn't work lol now it doesn't let me to turn on wifi so I guess something changed, thank you anyway

Comment: Also probably it didn't work because I already had the folder it appeared `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘rtw88’: File exists` so yeah I don't know why

Comment: Sorry to hear that news!  My research indicates a lot of problems with that wireless card and later versions of the Linux kernel.  There's a Git repo that has the latest drivers for your wireless card here - (https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)  Complete with step by step instuctions for installing -- if you want to give that a try.

Comment: Thank you so much! that fixed it I just followed the simple steps for my card in the GitHub repo and that was it, now it's working just fine.

Answer (score 6):

I've been having this problem of the network dropping, with a "?" in the
network icon, in the top right corner.

The following worked for me, without having to reboot the PC.

```
sudo nmcli networking off
```

and then,

```
sudo nmcli networking on
```

Comment: worth noting that you DO NOT want to do this if you are using ssh to connect to the device, it will kill ssh as well

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a kernel problem. When booting you can select Ubuntu Advanced Options from the GRUB menu and select the kernel which works for you (i choose generic kernel).

You can download and install the generic kernel form the UBUNTU kernels which i downloaded generic kernel following the steps provided in the link (https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/) solved the problem.

Note: I have installed generic kernel version V5.4.81 from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) seemed to work fine for me or you can choose the kernel you like.

Comment: Please be more precise with your answer. How do you do select advanced options? Which one is the right kernel? How do you know this kernel ist already installed? How do you install this kernel and make it the default option at startup?

Comment: Which kernel version works?

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem after upgrading kernel to `5.4.0-54-generic` on my lenovo laptop.

The solution was to reboot twice

I performed the upgrade using `sudo apt upgrade` and then rebooted, then selected continue booting at boot menu.

Upon reboot I had no wifi. The interface was missing. I rebooted again and everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

flow this steps to config:

0 config sys location

```
sudo tzselect
sudo cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai  /etc/localtime
date -R
```

1 install network tools

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

2 start wifi

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

3 edit wifi config

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

4 apply config

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off

sudo netplan --debug try
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan --debug apply
```