# problems with WiFi from last two three weeks ( HP Pavilion G6, using Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 )

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, hp

since last two three weeks I am experiencing problem with Wifi connection. I am really not sure when it start happening but I can say that it is persistent from last two - three weeks back.

When I log in the WiFi works and after sometime it dropped or freeze ( No download or Upload ), if I disconnect and reconnect then it works for 5-10 minutes and then again the problems starts.

On other devices the Wifi seems working fine. the router and laptop are at same place as they were.

I try to Google and seems like it is a problem with Kernel but when I try the 5.4.0.51-generic then also the problem is as it is.

I appreciate if someone can help me because without internet it is really less to do now a days on laptop.

thank you.

Comment: The problem is not with the kernel and that's what I said.

Comment: *"I try to Google and seems like it is a problem with Kernel"* - I'm asking you to elaborate on the source you have referenced.  You didn't give any other possible explanations.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230041/wifi-problems-with-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa

Comment: What is the Wi-Fi adapter? Is it the RTL8822BE?  Because that question/answer seems to be hardware-specific. (Most WiFi issues are hardware specific, after you rule out issues with the network configuration and signal strength). Since it worked 2-3 weeks ago, I really doubt that your problem is with the kernel, especially if that answer didn't work for you.   I suggest that you edit your question and include all of the spoils of your research and what you've done so far to diagnose/troubleshoot the problem.  Include the make/model of your adapter.