# It doesn't react to wi-fi

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, madwifi

Cannot connect to wifi, while all networks are available. When I tap on any of them, just nothing happens. Also in settings of networks I was connected, password doesn't shown. Problem isn't with wifi, cause smartphone and other computers are connected to them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi problems with Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230041/wifi-problems-with-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa)